# "This field is required." when sending JSON using POST with Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following JSON I'm trying to post:

```
[
    {
        "action_alert_details": [], 
        "action_email": [
            {
                "tskmail_attach": null, 
                "tskmail_id": 4444, 
                "tskmail_memo": "TEST!", 
                "tskmail_priority": 1, 
                "tskmail_subject": "TEST!", 
                "tskmail_to_ext": "blah@blah.com", 
                "tskmail_to_int": null
            }
        ], 
        "action_job_details": [], 
        "action_log_details": [], 
        "action_snmp_details": [], 
        "action_variable_details": [], 
        "nodmst_name": null, 
        "owner_name": "Operations                    ", 
        "servicemst_name": null, 
        "tskmst_desc": null, 
        "tskmst_id": 4444, 
        "tskmst_lstchgtm": "2014-09-17T16:02:29", 
        "tskmst_name": "act_test                     ", 
        "tskmst_public": "Y", 
        "tskmst_type": 1
    }
]
```

When sending it through the following view, it's complaining:

```
[
    {
        "action_email": [
            {
                "tskmail_id": "This field is required."
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But as you can see in my JSON at the top, it's there. So, why does my view not seem to recognize that it's there during serialization?

```
def put(self, request, format=None):

    data = request.DATA
    owner = data[0]['owner_name']
    ownerid = Owner.objects.filter(owner_name=owner).values_list('owner_id', flat=True)[0]
    data[0].update({'owner_id': ownerid})
    actid = data[0]['tskmst_id']
    actname = data[0]['tskmst_name']
    if data[0]['nodmst_name'] == None:
        data[0].update({'nodmst_id': None})
    else:
        nodname = data[0]['nodmst_name']
        nodid = Nodmst.objects.filter(nodmst_name=nodname).values_list('nodmst_id', flat=True)[0]
        data[0].update({'nodmst_id': nodid})
    if data[0]['servicemst_name'] == None:
        data[0].update({'servicemst_id': None})
    else:
        servicename = data[0]['servicemst_name']
        serviceid = Servicemst.objects.filter(servicemst_name=servicename).values_list('servicemst_id', flat=True)[0]
        data[0].update({'servicemst_id': serviceid})
    if Tskmst.objects.filter(tskmst_name=actname).exists():
        data[0]['tskmst_id'] = Tskmst.objects.filter(tskmst_name=actname).values_list('tskmst_id', flat=True)[0]
        data[0]['action_email'][0]['tskmail_id'] = Tskmst.objects.filter(tskmst_name=actname).values_list('tskmst_id', flat=True)[0]
    else:
        maxtskid = Tskmst.objects.latest('tskmst_id').tskmst_id
        data[0]['tskmst_id'] = maxtskid + 1
        data[0]['action_email'][0]['tskmail_id'] = maxtskid + 1
        Tblcnt.objects.filter(tblcnt_tblname='tskmst').update(tblcnt_lstid=(maxtskid +1))
        Tblcnt.objects.filter(tblcnt_tblname='tskmail').update(tblcnt_lstid=(maxtskid +1))
    serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(data=request.DATA, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
#            serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is my serializers that are pulling the data together:

```
class ActionMailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tskmail
        resource_name = 'tskmail'

class ActionPUTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_id = serializers.Field(source='owner_id')
    action_email = ActionMailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Tskmst
        resource_name = 'tskmst'
        depth = 1
        fields = ('tskmst_id', 'tskmst_name', 'tskmst_desc', 'tskmst_type', 'owner_id', 'tskmst_public',
                'tskmst_lstchgtm', 'nodmst_id', 'servicemst_id',  'action_email', 'action_alert_details',
                'action_snmp_details', 'action_job_details', 'action_log_details', 'action_variable_details')
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong. Try to log the output of 'tskmail_id'. Put `print data[0]['action_email'][0]['tskmail_id']` after `data = request.DATA` and look after the output in the console. Maybe try the same in the if/else block where you manipulate this value and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for the potential that other people might experience this issue which seems to be pertaining to it being a legacy DB.  The problem lies in the fact that the PK field in "tskmail" table is also a FK to "tskmst".

See [Multi-Column Primary Key support](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys) for more info.

What I ended up doing is making another set of models strictly for PUT that has no FK relationship but is strictly an Integer Field.

```
class TskmailPOST(models.Model):
    tskmail_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    tskmail_to_int = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_to_ext = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_subject = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_memo = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    tskmail_priority = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tskmail_attach = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tskmail'
```

Instead of -

```
class TskmailPOST(models.Model):
    tskmail_id = models.ForeignKey(Tskmst, db_column='tskmail_id', primary_key=True)
    tskmail_to_int = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_to_ext = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_subject = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tskmail_memo = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    tskmail_priority = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tskmail_attach = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tskmail'
```

Then I had to call 2 separate serializers and using the POST data, break it into 2 separate dict files and validate the first, load it then validate the second and load it.